# C - wait, fail when getting the returned value

Tags: c, shell, fork, wait

I have the following problem: In my code, here in line 83, I have this: `check = wait(NULL);`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

//---------------------------------
//Function: parse_cmdline(const char* cmdline)
//This function takes the input from stdin
//and returns it as array of strings.
//If stdin is /bin/ls -l /usr/include
//the function will return ["/bin/ls","-l","/usr/include"]
//---------------------------------
char** parse_cmdline(const char* cmdline) {

        int count, word_count = 0;
        char** line_parsed, line_return;
        char *pch, *cmdline_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(cmdline)+1));
        strcpy(cmdline_copy, cmdline);

        pch = strtok(cmdline_copy," \n\t\r");

        while (pch != NULL) {
                ++word_count;          
        pch = strtok(NULL, " \n\t\r");
        }

        line_parsed = (char**)malloc((word_count+1)*sizeof(char*));
        count = 0;

        strcpy(cmdline_copy, cmdline);
        pch = strtok(cmdline_copy," \n\t\r");

        while (pch != NULL) {          
                line_parsed[count] = (char*)malloc((strlen(pch) + 1)*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(line_parsed[count], pch);
                ++count;
        pch = strtok(NULL," \n\t\r");
        }

        line_parsed[count] = NULL;
        free(cmdline_copy);
        return line_parsed;
}

int main() {

        int count = 0, check;
        size_t size;
        char* line;
        char** cmdline;

        while(1) {

                check = 0;
                printf("$Monkey Eats:< ");
                getline(&line, &size, stdin);
                cmdline = parse_cmdline(line);

                pid_t pid = fork();
                if (pid == -1) {
                        perror("fork");
                        return -1;
                } else if(pid == 0) {
                        struct stat _stat;
                                stat(cmdline[0],&_stat);
                        if(_stat.st_mode & S_IXUSR){   
                                execvp(cmdline[0], cmdline);                           
                        }else fprintf(stderr,"%s: Permission denied!\n",cmdline[0]);
                                perror("");
                        exit(1);
                }else {
                        check = wait(NULL);
                }
                count = 0;
                while(cmdline[count] != NULL) {
                        free(cmdline[count]);
                        ++count;
                }
                free(cmdline);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It makes me a problem. When I run it and when I type a command I have the following message:

```
$Monkey Eats:< ls
ls: Permission denied!
No such file or directory
```

If I have only `wait(NULL);` the program runs normally without a problem. Can somebody tell me what is the problem? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is trying to run `ls`.  `execvp()` doesn't know where `ls` is.  Try running `/bin/ls` as your command.

Comment: but if I have only wait(NULL); without saving it's value in check, it works normally even if i don't type the path.

Comment: If you have `wait(NULL) ;`  how do you know it works?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: `stat(cmdline[0],&_stat);` - the return code is not checked. What if file not found ? The program continues, and finds that `_stat.st_mode & S_IXUSR` is 0 (randomly).

However you may test the program as is with "`/bin/ls`" as input..